# How to set Timezone for DynamoDBAutogenerated timestamp in spring data

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to add time attributes in dynamoDb table. I have added @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp annotation on my date containers but it seems to pick the 00:00 as the default timezone.

```
@get:DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
    var createdAt: String? = null

    @get:DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
    var updateAt: String? = null
```

Comment: You cannot choose a time zone or a time offset. It always uses UTC.

Comment: But is there any way out for this to have an offset of +05:30?

Comment: Like I said, you cannot choose a time zone or **time offset**. Why do you need to use an offset in your database?

Comment: it is a zone only database and this may lead to incorrect information or else i have to do manual offset for this to store correct information according to our timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set a zone offset for `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp`, but it is possible to create your own implementation of [@DynamoDBAutoGenerator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGenerator.html) along with a [corresponding annotation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGenerated.html).

Here's how you would accomplish it in Java. (It looks like you're using Kotlin, but it should be straightforward for you to convert this.)

```
@DynamoDBAutoGenerated(generator=AutoGeneratedTimestampWithOffset.Generator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface AutoGeneratedTimestampWithOffset {

    /**
     * See {@link ZoneOffset#of(String)} for valid values.
     */
    String offset();
    DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy strategy() default DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS;

    public class Generator implements DynamoDBAutoGenerator<String> {
        private final String offset;
        private final DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy strategy;

        public Generator(final Class<String> targetType, final AutoGeneratedTimestampWithOffset annotation) {
            this.offset = annotation.offset();
            this.strategy = annotation.strategy();
        }

        @Override
        public DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy getGenerateStrategy() {
            return strategy;
        }

        @Override
        public final String generate(final String currentValue) {
            return OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.of(offset)).toString();
        }
    }
}
```

In your `@DynamoDBTable` class, you would use this annotation like this:

```
@get:AutoGeneratedTimestampWithOffset(offset="+05:30", strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
var createdAt: String? = null

@get:AutoGeneratedTimestampWithOffset(offset="+05:30", strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
var updateAt: String? = null
```